# margin % working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I'm trying to have a webpage to look the same in Chrome and in Firefox, as you would. I have a gallery with a set of divs, those divs have a margin bottom that is a percentage, which works fine in Chrome, the divs have this class and styles:

```
.opacityLayer {
  background-color: #66B9BF;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 17px 10px -10px
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;

  **margin-bottom: 3%;**

  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

For Firefox, I tried:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .opacityLayer {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Which works, but if I try:

```
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .opacityLayer {
            margin-bottom: 3%;
        }
    }
```

It stops working. How come Firefox is not accepting a percentage here like Chrome does and only pixels? I should add that both html and body have a 100% height.

Comment: Please provide a complete working example (build the jsfiddle/snippet the reproduce your problem).

Comment: Works for me using Firefox 50.0.2 on Mac - http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/vgYYxp.